# hasClass in if condition is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not able to find why my `.hasClass` is not working.

I am using the Quick Search jQuery plugin and my code is below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.quicksearch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input#id_search').quicksearch('div#booklist div.cover', {
            'show': function () {
                $(this).removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
            },
            'hide': function () {
                $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
            }
        });


    if ($('div#booklist div.cover').hasClass('hide')) {
        alert("Yay ! Its working now.");
    }

});// DOM ends here ..before editing it was above if statement.
</script>
```

If anyone find error in my code, If so please let me know.

Even I tried with different condition like `if ($('.hide').css('display') == 'none')` but still it's not working.

There is no error in the console and it is adding `hide` class as well and there are so many `hide` class.

**HTML:**

```
    <form action="#" id="searchform"><div><input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="s" class="search" id="id_search" placeholder="Enter here"/></div></form>

<div id="booklist">
    <h4>Title-1</h4>
    <div class="cover"><a href="link" rel="bookmark" /></a>Sub title</div>
    <div class="cover"><a href="link" rel="bookmark" /></a>Sub title</div>
    <div class="cover"><a href="link" rel="bookmark" /></a>Sub title</div>
    <div class="cover"><a href="link" rel="bookmark" /></a>Sub title</div>
    <div class="cover"><a href="link" rel="bookmark" /></a>Sub title</div>

    <h4>Title-2</h4>
    <div class="cover"><a href="link" rel="bookmark" /></a>Sub title</div>
    <div class="cover"><a href="link" rel="bookmark" /></a>Sub title</div>
    .
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, you're running the `if` condition before the DOM is ready so the `#booklist div.cover` element won't be available yet. Also, it looks like you're trying to run it once on load when the element wouldn't have the `hide` class anyway. What behaviour are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you adding the class `hide` after the document has loaded? Or does there exist some DOM element with that class name directly in the HTML code? If there is no class `hide` directly in the HTML code you have written, then this code fails because the `if` condition fails even before you happened to change the class name, as there exists no such element yet.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just put the code inside the if in the hide function from quicksearch?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Actually I want to hide the `<h4>` tag which is just before `<div class="cover">`

Comment: @Twix can you please add that to the question, along with your HTML.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Edited .. and there was typo as well in jQuery code which is also edited ..

Answer (score 2):

You must put your code in the `$(document).ready` callback. Right now it's executed before the `#booklist` element is added to the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

You should call you jQuery condition when the DOM is ready or activate it with anonymous function like this:

```
(function() {
     if ($('div#booklist div.cover').hasClass('hide')) {
         alert("Yay ! Its working now.");
     }
})();
```